# Proving $∀ε>0:x<y+\epsilon ⇒ x<y$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, real-numbers

> If $x, y \in \Bbb R$ and $x<y+\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon >0$, then $x<y$.

Okay so I went about this by proving the contrapositive.

Proof: Let $x,y\in\Bbb R$ and let $\epsilon>0$. Suppose $x\ge y$. Take $\epsilon = x-y$. This implies that $x=y+\epsilon$, as needed.

Is this a valid proof or not?

Comment: The conclusion should be $x\leq y$.

Comment: If $$\epsilon=x-y$$ then your epsilon would be negative!

Comment: Why would it be negative if $x \ge y$?

Comment: 1) The statment is false so your proof must be invalid 2).   If $x = y$ then $\epsilon = x-y = 0 \not > 0$. And that's why the statement is false.  If $x=y$ then $x=y < y + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ but $x \not < y$.  So the statement is false.  What do you think the *true* statement would be? (Hint:  You proof *does* prove the true statement.)

Comment: I do have to give you credit in that your proof *is* absolutely the correct idea and it *WOULD* have worked if the statement had been given properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement you want to prove is not true.

Take $x = y =0$. You have, for all $\varepsilon > 0$, $x < y + \varepsilon$ (because $\varepsilon > 0$), but of course you don't have $x < y$.

Answer (score 5):

The proof is invalid for the simple fact that the statement is false, so you cannot prove it.

The correct statement is “if, for all $\varepsilon>0$, $x<y+\varepsilon$, then $x\le y$”.

Now your proof works! Suppose $x>y$ (that is, “not $x\le y$”) and take $\varepsilon=x-y$; then $\varepsilon>0$ and $x=y+\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

1) The statement is false.

Counter example:  Let $x = y$.  Then $x = y < y+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ but $x \not < y$.

2)  Your error is in claiming setting $\epsilon = x - y$.  If $x =y$ then that $\epsilon \not > 0$.

Your proof is doomed to fail for $x = y$ because the statement is false for $x =y$.

3) But you have proven that $x>y$ is impossible. That would mean if $\epsilon = x - y > 0$ then $x = y + \epsilon$ which contradicts our hypothesis that $x < y + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

4) So a *TRUE* statement would be: if $x < y + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ then $x \le y$ and you *successfully* have proven that.